# Change options of select field in Zurb Foundation via jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, zurb-foundation

I am working on a contact form with two select fields. The second select field is disabled by default and gets populated with options depending on the selection in the first select box. It all works fine using "normal" select fields but since I am working with Zurb's Foundation Framework, it gets a bit more tricky.

I can't get Foundation's custom select field to update its values as well. The hidden select field is populated with the correct content but it doesn't show up as link on the page. I found a couple topics here that dealt with a similar issue and tried to fire `$('#treatment-select').trigger('change', true);` but unfortunately it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

*Code is not complete. I shortened it for demonstration purposes*

```
 jQuery('#treatment-category').change(function() {

    var target = jQuery('#treatment-category option:selected').val();

    if (target == "Face Surgery") {
        jQuery('#treatment-select').prop('disabled', false);

        jQuery('#treatment-select').find('option:not(:first)').remove();

        var treatments = {
        "Brow lift":"brow-lift",
        "Cheeck fat removal":'cheek-fat-removal',
        "Chin implant":"chin-implant"
        };

        var val, text;

        for (text in treatments) {
            val = treatments[text];
               jQuery('<option/>').val(val).text(text).appendTo(jQuery('#treatment-select'));
        }
        $('#treatment-select').trigger('change', true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally found the solution. Instead of firing `trigger('change'); I uses the following to make it work:

```
Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#hiddenSelectBoxID'), true);`
```